# How to document Java Web service API

Tags: java, web-services, documentation

I have a Java web service and want to document the public API so the documentation is able to be browsed from the web from the same URL as the web service. How is this usually done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way of doing so.  The WSDL is not humanly readable, and the page listing - if any - the possible WSDL's is automatically generated.

You will need to investigate how the web service layer you have chosen, do it, and see if there is any way to "hook into" that mechanism.

Comment: I was kind of hoping for something like the .Net feature where you could annotate your web service class and it would automatically create a webpage for the webservice at the root with the annotations.

I am just going to generate a javadoc and post that.

Answer (score 1):

There is wsdldocumentation tag:

```
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Your Documentation</wsdl:documentation>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a documentation tool like iDocIt! to add documentation to the WSDL. It is an Open Source Eclipse Plugin for documenting APIs. http://code.google.com/p/idocit